# ECDH public and private keys generation with .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am porting nodejs code to .Net and I am stuck at this part where I need to generate public and private keys.

Javascript code:

```
const dh = crypto.createECDH('prime256v1');
let privk = dh.getPrivateKey();
let pubk = dh.getPublicKey();
```

I tried the same with .Net C# with

```
var ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256, null, new CngKeyCreationParameters { ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport }));

var privateKey = ecdh.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
var publickey = ecdh.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

However when I tried to exchange those keys generated with C# with the Google FCM server, I got invalid argument error. When I copy the generated byte[] array from nodejs to .Net C# code as constants it works. It is obvious that generated keys are not meeting the requirement of the server. Since I am working with undocumented interface I can't tell why the keys are not accepted. I can see that the keys generated with nodejs are in 32 bytes in length for the private key and 65 bytes in length for the public key. The keys generated from C# are 140 and 96 bytes in length. How to generate keys in C# to match the key properties in nodejs?

Comment: The c# keys are probably adding padding.  Padding adds random bits to end of key so the real key length is not detectable.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using Bouncy Castle

```
            ECKeyPairGenerator gen = new ECKeyPairGenerator("ECDH");
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            X9ECParameters ecp = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
            ECDomainParameters ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecp.Curve, ecp.G, ecp.N, ecp.H, ecp.GetSeed());
            ECKeyGenerationParameters ecgp = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, secureRandom);
            gen.Init(ecgp);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair eckp = gen.GenerateKeyPair();

            ECPublicKeyParameters ecPub = (ECPublicKeyParameters)eckp.Public;
            ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPri = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)eckp.Private;

            byte[] publicKeyBytes = ecPub.Q.GetEncoded();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ECDiffieHellman to encrypt messages. You have two options: Static-static ECDH and static-ephemeral ECDH:

For static-static ECDH the receiver will need to know the sender's public key (this might or might not be an option in your application). You should also have some data that is unique for this message (it might be a serial-number you get from somewhere else in the protocol or database-row or whatever or it might be a nonce). You then use ECDH to generate a secret key and use that to encrypt your data. This will give you your desired encrypted data length of 16 bytes, but it is not completely asymmetric: the encryptor is also able to decrypt the messages (again: this might or might not be a problem in your application).

Static-ephemeral is a bit different: here the encryptor generates a temporary (ephemeral) EC key pair. He then uses this key pair together with the receiver's public key to generate a secret key which can be used to encrypt the data. Finally, he sends the public key of the ephemeral key pair to the receiver together with the encrypted data. This might fit better into your application, but the complete encrypted data will now be 2*32+16=80 bytes using ECDH-256 and AES (as GregS notes you can save 32 bytes by only sending the x-coordinate of the public-key, but I do not believe that .NET exposes the functionality to recalculate the y-coordinate).

Here is a small class that will do static-static ECDH:

```
public static class StaticStaticDiffieHellman
{
  private static Aes DeriveKeyAndIv(ECDiffieHellmanCng privateKey, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicKey, byte[] nonce)
  {
    privateKey.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
    privateKey.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
    privateKey.SecretAppend = nonce;
    byte[] keyAndIv = privateKey.DeriveKeyMaterial(publicKey);
    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(keyAndIv, 0, key, 0, 16);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(keyAndIv, 16, iv, 0, 16);

    Aes aes = new AesManaged();
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    return aes;
  }

  public static byte[] Encrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng privateKey, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicKey, byte[] nonce, byte[] data){
    Aes aes = DeriveKeyAndIv(privateKey, publicKey, nonce);
    return aes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
  }

  public static byte[] Decrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng privateKey, ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey publicKey, byte[] nonce, byte[] encryptedData){
    Aes aes = DeriveKeyAndIv(privateKey, publicKey, nonce);
    return aes.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData,0, encryptedData.Length);
  }
}

// Usage:

ECDiffieHellmanCng key1 = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();    
ECDiffieHellmanCng key2 = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();

byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TestTestTestTes");
byte[] nonce = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("whatever");

byte[] encryptedData = StaticStaticDiffieHellman.Encrypt(key1, key2.PublicKey, nonce, data);

Console.WriteLine(encryptedData.Length); // 16

byte[] decryptedData = StaticStaticDiffieHellman.Decrypt(key2, key1.PublicKey, nonce, encryptedData);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData));
```